# MySQL COUNT query returns only one value from a CASE expression

Tags: mysql, database, count, case

I have a table with a `score` column and depending on the score amount I want to group them in different 'issuers' and count them.

The problem is that I'm getting only the 'Passives' when the `score` records actually meets also 'Detractors' and 'Promoters'. Here is my query:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN score < 133 THEN 'Detractors'
    WHEN score BETWEEN 133 AND 209 THEN 'Passives'
    WHEN score = 210 THEN 'Promotors'
  END AS 'Issuer',
  COUNT(1) AS 'Amount'
FROM my_data
```

Any suggestion on what's going on?

Comment: Missing the GROUP BY clause? `... FROM my_data GROUP BY Issuer`

Comment: what data type is the score column in the my_data table?  char, varchar may cause weird implicit casting issues.

Comment: Please show us sample data, current results and expected results, and you will probably receive relevant answers.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel you are right, I added the GROUP BY clause and is working perfectly now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query which contains [aggregate functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html) (like `COUNT()` or `MAX()`) without a `GROUP BY` clause will always return exactly one row. If a column (even a calculated column like your `Issuer`) can potentially contain diffrent values, the server has to choose one of them.

The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) states:

> In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group,
>   so unless they are the same, the values chosen are nondeterministic,
>   which is probably not what you want.

In your case `Issuer` can contain three values ("Detractors", "Passives", "Promotors") and the server has shosen "Passives".

Note that with [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) mode enabled (which is default since version 5.7) your query would fail with an error.

> `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`
>
> Reject queries for which the select list, `HAVING` condition, or `ORDER BY`
>   list refer to nonaggregated columns that are neither named in the
>   `GROUP BY` clause nor are functionally dependent on (uniquely determined
>   by) `GROUP BY` columns.

The solution in your case is rather simple: Include `GROUP BY Issuer` in the query

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN score < 133 THEN 'Detractors'
    WHEN score BETWEEN 133 AND 209 THEN 'Passives'
    WHEN score = 210 THEN 'Promotors'
  END AS 'Issuer',
  COUNT(1) AS 'Amount'
FROM my_data 
GROUP BY `Issuer`
```